# Mouse Tilt horizontal scrolling is not working in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, mousewheel

I have a

```
 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
```

with horizontal scrollbar. When I perform mouse tilt on this DataGridView, the contents are not scrolled horizontally. But in

```
 ListView
```

when I perform mouse tilt the contents will scroll horizontally. So should I set any additional properties in the DataGridView to enable the mouse tilt ? Or is it a bug in DataGridView ?

Comment: DataGridView gets `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL(0x020e)` message. But horizontal scrolling is not happening in DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
      //get current selected rows
      DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rc = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;

      if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
      {
        if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue && rc.Count > 0)
        {
          int nextrow = rc[0].Index + 1;
          dataGridView1.Rows[nextrow].Selected = true;
        }        
      }
    }
```

Comment: Tilting the Mouse Wheel on a DGV here raises neither the `Scroll` not the `MouseWheel` event  :-(

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this effect, you need to create a custom DataGridView.

```cs
    public sealed class MouseTiltableDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        private const int WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEHWHEEL)
            {
                short w = (short)((m.WParam.ToInt32() >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
                if (HorizontalScrollingOffset + w >= 0)
                {
                    HorizontalScrollingOffset += w;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```